# Root Mean Square error (RMS) to compare two solution methods?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit

I solved nonlinear reaction diffusion equation in two method, and I want to make comparison between my outputs by using RMS error.

The first solution is $u_1$, a $21\times 21$ matrix, and
the second solution is $u_2$, a $21\times 21$ matrix.

I used RMS error in Matlab as
$\text{error}^2=\text{mean}(u_1-u_2)^2$.

Is this the correct way to show the difference between two methods and to use RMS error?

What is the best way to compare two results?

Comment: You might want to look at another metric as well, probably MAPE (mean absolute percentage error).

Answer (score 1):

I have come to respect NIST.  I would like to see a 4-plot of the error.

http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/4plot.htm

It has a good mix of unique frameworks to consider error.

- histogram -> pdf -> pdf statistics
- run sequence -> same stuff from shewhart jump, ramp in mean, jump in stdev, ramp in stdev
- lag shows time dependence, gaussian blob means random, otherwise means timeseries can apply
- qq plot shows in a form that allows quantiles to be estimated, and distribution center and confidence vs. reference distribution (often normal distribution)

If you want to stand on the shoulders of giants, NIST is a great place to start.

http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda34.htm